# Solve a linear system with unknowns on both sides and a known inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a linear system of the form:

$Ax = b$

I know some of the values in x and want to know their corresponding values in b. The remaining values in b are all 0's. The matrix A represents a convolution and is diagonalised by the fft matrix, so finding (or at least applying) its inverse is trivial. The system is very large (~2M by 2M), symmetric, and every element is positive.

Does anyone know if there is a fast way to find the unknowns? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it is "trivial" to find $A^{-1}$, then $Ax=b$ yields $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: But there are still unknowns on both sides?

Comment: But we have a complete solution. The unkwowns in $x$ are given by the "unknowns" in $b$, which we can put arbitrarily then. Like in integers, the equation $x=a^{-1}b$.

Comment: Could you add an example or answer? I don't see how this gives the unknowns

Comment: Can you give an example of a small system, analogous to your "very large" one? Then we can write down all solutions, as explained. Perhaps this helps to see what you need.